# Killing the task after specific period of time [after other task have been killed]

Tags: python

Hello i'am a total beginner in python and I am trying to execute a code which will kill a task after a specific period of time when the other tasks have been killed.
i've found those commands while searching the stackoverflow archive but somehow the timer does not work (the first part with taskkill of crome and potplayer works just fine, the problem is with shutting down of bitcomet after a time given)

Python version : 3.6.0

Code that i've used:

```
import os
import timer
os.system ("taskkill /f /im chrome.exe")
os.system ("taskkill /f /im PotPlayerMini64.exe")

def bitshut():
  os.system("taskkill /f /im BitComet.exe")
t = timer(3600.00, bitshut)
t.start()
#preferably i would like to shutdown bitcomet when the download has been 
finished

print("Your computer will shutdown now")

os.system ("shutdown /s /t 5")
```

Comment: `timer` is not a standard Python module I know of. It also seems strange that you would call the actual module, not something like `timer.timer`. You may want to clarify what the `timer` module is, and update your code example to something valid.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `time.sleep`.

Comment: That `t.start()` call makes me think that the timer is a [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects), but I don't understand how that `import timer` is working.